# Select the last date of that month and display all data which are within that month

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a datepicker calendar, so when I select the last date of that month I want it to display all data which are within that month

For example when I select 31-March-2017 it must display data from 1-31 March.

Here is my code...

```
SELECT sum(income_amount)from income where (income_date Between '". 
    $_POST['transactiondate']. "'  and '". 
    $_POST['transactiondate'] ."') and traditionalcouncil_name='BAKGAGA-BA- MAAKE' AND 
    financialyear_id = '". $Finyear ."'
```

Comment: how has this been stored in the database

Comment: so don't select between transactiondate and transactiondate, but between transactiondate and 1 month earlier...?

Comment: `where (date_trunc('month', income_date) = date_trunc('month', '". 
    $_POST['transactiondate']. "')`